# Is there a way to indent HTML or PHP code instantly using a program such as Scite?

Tags: php, mysql, indentation, scite

If I have the following code:

```
<div id="nla">hi</div><table>
  <tr>
      <td>hi</td></tr></table>
```

I want to use Scite or any other program to take this as input, and spit it out as:

```
<div id="nla">
  hi
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hi
    </td>
  </tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML tidy will do this.  It produced

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nla">
    hi
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>hi</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and many error from your sample. Give it the whole page!